# В сайдбаре, при наведении, необходимо сделать острый конец?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

[image: пример ховер эффекта]

Пытался делать через after и background, однако не происходит выравнивания по высоте. Если высота слишком большая, стрелка не отображается и фон слишком далеко.

```css
.sidebar{
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        background: #aaa;
    }

    .sidebar ul{
        padding: 0;
    }

    .sidebar ul li{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    .sidebar ul li:hover{
        background: url('https://imgur.com/UnnvNAN') no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Тестовый пункт</li>
            <li>Тестовый пункт Тестовый пункт Тестовый пункт</li>
            <li>Тестовый пункт</li>
            <li>Тестовый пунктТестовый пункт</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Скиньте свой код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясню:

По идее я меняю при событии :focus картинку, в моём случае это svg закодированная [этим сервисом](http://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) в background, и если событие :focus наступило я просто меняю картинку т.е background ну а для анимации сделал transition

Вот собственно и вся наука

```css
:root {
  --color: blue;
}

* {
  user-select: none;
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 208 59' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0,-237.27976)'%3E%3Cpath d='m 0,237.27976 h 173.88393 l 1.38731,33.39212 L 173.88393,297 H 0 Z' fill='gray'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
}

li span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
}

li:focus {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 208 59' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg transform='translate(0,-237.27976)'%3E%3Cpath d='m 0,237.27976 h 173.88393 l 10.1452,32.84475 L 173.88393,297 H 0 Z' fill='cyan'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

li:focus span {
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<li tabindex="-1">
  <span>lorem4</span>
</li>

<li tabindex="-1">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span>
</li>

<li tabindex="-1">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing</span>

</li>

<li tabindex="-1">
  <span>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem nesciunt laborum deserunt, unde cupiditate itaque illo voluptatibus architecto veniam dolore sint est iure temporibus esse, fuga officia expedita aperiam ipsa ipsam. Atque doloremque soluta delectus optio sapiente minus perspiciatis perferendis enim iste, qui necessitatibus harum natus? Explicabo, distinctio. Molestiae, corporis.

     </span>
</li>
```

Comment: А как сделать стрелку адаптивной по высоте?

Comment: @КириллМироненко  наверно резиновый по высоте ?